# Token field json syntax error bootstrap

Tags: json, bootstrap-tokenfield

I have around 700 product list in my Databse table.

I am using bootstrap's tokenfield for auotcomplete, i have to use auto complete in search textbox.

I am getting syntax error :

`SyntaxError: missing ] after element list`

...B','Lino Perros Men's Leather Wallet - Pink','Lenovo A269i','Lenovo S660 - Tita**

in console.

```js
<?php $t = $this->general_model->auto_complete_sug(); ?>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#tokenfield-2').tokenfield({
        autocomplete: {
            source: <?=$t?>,
            delay : 100
        },
        limit: 1,
        minLength: 1,
        showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="span2" name="search" id="tokenfield-2" placeholder="Search...">

In my model: I have created this functions:


public function auto_complete_sug()
 {
  $data = $this->auto_complete_token_fun();

  $data1 = explode(',', $data);
  $data1 = array_unique($data1);
  foreach ($data1 as $value1) {
   $temparr[] = $value1;
  }
  $str = '[';
  $c = count($temparr);
  $counter = 0;
  foreach ($temparr as $val) {
   $counter++;
   $str .= "'".$val."'";
   if($counter < $c){
    $str .= ",";
   }
  }
  $str .= ']';
  return $str;
 }
                              
                              
public function auto_complete_token_fun()
 {
  // $this->db->query("SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 10000000");
  $q = $this->db->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( sub_category_name ) AS scname
   FROM `tbl_subcategory` WHERE status = 'Active' ");
  if($q->num_rows() > 0)
  {
   $d = $q->row_array();
   return $d['scname'];
  }
  else
  {
   return '';
  }
 }
```

Please help!!

Comment: when i echo the data,it is displaying in correct format, but when i give that data to source property of auto-complete that time i am getting error.

Comment: please answer someone..

Comment: Your `source: <?=$t?>,` should link to an url with Json. Is your `$t` an url with Json  ?